# Send email to pushbullet?

Tags: pushbullet

The website "PushBullet.com" is webwashed(filtered) by our proxy, at work.

But I really need to send some notifications to my devices.

Is there a way to send them thru the good old email protocol ?

Answer (score 0):

So there is no officially supported feature for this, but you can sort of fake it using the existing email-to-push feature.

Send a push to an email address that is not a pushbullet account, such as `yourgmailaccount+randomstring@gmail.com`.  It will have a from address of `someotherrandomstring@pushbulletuseremail.com`.

You can then send emails to that address, and they should show up in your pushes list.

Comment: Do you have a link to the _email-to-push feature_?

Answer (score 0):

Proposed method with random strings in email address doesn't work.

[This method works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24130342/1472042). Not an email, just pure notification as required.

[The library developer](https://github.com/Azelphur/pyPushBullet) suggests also command line notification send. Simple and handy.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to do something similar so I could get pushbullet notifications from cron jobs, and came across this:

https://github.com/side2k/email2pb

<strike>I haven't gotten a chance to try it yet but I think this will do what you're wanting.</strike> Just tested it, and it works really well if you're able to run a postfix server.

Answer (score 0):

I use Zapier for this (you can do it with a free account).

Set up a Zap to search for new mail under a label (I use "pushbullet-notify"), and send any message there to Pushbullet.

Then in Gmail just create filters for any mails you want PB notifications on, applying the same label.

The notification may be delayed up to 15 minutes from the time the email is received and labeled (free accounts check every 15 minutes).